# SQL Server Regex - Find single instance of character

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, sql-server-2014, sql-like

Given the following test data, I want to return all rows that contain a single ampersand (&) character that does not have another ampersand character directly before or after.

```
CREATE TABLE #RegexTest (Vals VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO #RegexTest (Vals) VALUES
('&'),       /* match */
('&&'),
('1 & 2'),   /* match */
('1 && 2'),
('1 && 2&')  /* match */
```

I have tried the following method using negative lookahead and negative look behind:

```
SELECT *
FROM #RegexTest
WHERE Vals LIKE '%(?<!&)&(?!&)%'
```

But this returns no rows. How would I go about this?

Comment: Your `LIKE` expression will only find rows with the field `Vals` containing strings that contain the literal string `(?<!&)&(?!&)` as SQL server doesn't support regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the pattern `%[^&]&[^&]%` to find an `&` that does not have the same character before and after it. Strings shorter than 3 characters must be padded for this trick to work:

```sql
WHERE CONCAT('|', vals, '|') LIKE '%[^&]&[^&]%'
```